# Converting a selection of vertices into a mesh

Tags: vertices

Can anyone help me convert a selection of vertices into a mesh?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It is a little hard to tell from your screenshot what you are trying to achieve. Consider adding a -blend file.  Are you asking to connect those loose vertices with edges to form a mesh?

Comment: I would like to create a flat surface topology from the data. Like the following add-on that has been abandoned. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pointcloudskin/

Comment: Why don't you download Blender 2.63, use the PointCloudSkinner Addon and then rexport to a curent Blender`?

Comment: @Leander because I would prefer to find a way to use one piece of software if it is possible.

Comment: Since this addon seems to be your best bet, it should be revived. It seems to be really well documented with the pdf. What do you think would be more useful: a rewrite for 2.79 or 2.8? Would you be willing to contribute with time and coding?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with unconnected vertices in a rectangular grid with random z-coordinates. I've solved it in Blender 3.3 by using geometry nodes to place a 3x3 grid instance in each vertex and then merging the cubes' vertices by distance. In order to merge the vertices I first scale down by 0.01 the z coordinates and after merging restore the heights by up-scaling by 100.

Comment: see this setup: https://i.imgur.com/jibFcLe.png